# In a python function, do I need to pre-allocate a value which appears conditionally under if?

Tags: python, function, variables

In a python function, do I need to pre-allocate a value which appears conditionally under if?

```
def func(x,y):
    if x == 1:
        z = 2
    else: pass

    if y == 1:
        print(z)
    else: pass
```

I see the problem here that `print(z)` may blow up if `x != 1` and `y == 1`. To potentially prevent this error raiser, do I declare `z = None` at the beginning of the function or use try-except to print `z` or other ways to do? What would be the best practice?

Comment: First of all, get rid of these spurious `else: pass` lines :D

Comment: There is not really such a thing as "allocation" in Python code (all that kind of stuff happens behind the scenes), and there is no "initialization" either (the code doesn't care when the name got its value assigned). But you are expected to ensure that values are assigned before they are used regardless of the initial state, yes. *There isn't really a general-purpose solution for this; you need to think about your logic* and find a clear expression for it. For example: should you actually `print` at all in the case you identified? If not, maybe you really want to nest the `if`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is Yes.

If you want to do something like: `print(z)` later in the function, then `z` should be assigned to first.

You have some options:

```
def func(x, y):
    if x == 1:
        z = 2
    else:
        z = None

# or
def func(x, y):
    z = None
    if x == 1:
        z = 2

# or
def func(x, y):
    z = 2 if x == 1 else None
```

Answer (score 0):

to prevent the "blow up" you have to define your variable at the beginning of your function or before to be used, in your case you may use:

```
def func(x, y):
    z = None
    if x == 1:
        z = 2

    if z and y == 1:
        print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
def func(x,y):
    z = 2 if x == 1 else None
    print(z)
```

That means `z` will always be assigned by `2` or `None` if `x == 1` or else respectively.